# Aws Event Bridge Rule Not Firing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

I have an EventBridge rule attached to my AWS SQS queue with the following event pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.sqs"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["sqs.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["ReceiveMessage"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "queueUrl": ["amy-sqs-arn"]
    },
    "resources": ["my-sqs-arn"]
  }
}
```

Currently, when I add a message to the SQS queue, the EventBridge rule doesn't trigger (I've monitored the EventBridge rule). I suspect there might be a configuration problem between EventBridge and SQS. Additionally, the Lambda function attached to the EventBridge rule is also not getting triggered.

Please keep in mind that I'm new to AWS, so I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue."

Comment: You cannot listen on sqs data events, e.g. `SendMessage` or `ReceiveMessage`, that is simply not supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-logging-using-cloudtrail.html Why would you want that in the first place? Subscribe the lambda to the queue to get the messages, end of options.

Comment: i wanted to trigger a lambda and do video processing in a spot instance . and i need to consider the states of spot ec2 like if it crash the video needs to be re processed .

Comment: So? Then subscribe whatever processing you have to the queue, that is how queues are supposed to work. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-cost-effective-queue-workers-with-amazon-sqs-and-amazon-ec2-spot-instances/ . Not through EventBridge.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about it. Thanks for the advice. Is there anything else very important that I should consider with this approach?